# What happens at the interface between a solid and a fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, discretization, calculus

I am doing an MPM simulation of water colliding against a solid, I am currently encoding the model for collision forces and I am realising something isn't clicking.

Let us assume the fluid experiences no friction from the solid itself, only viscous forces. The fluid we will assume has a density of 1 g/ml. The solid has constant and uniform density. Let us say that the material description tells us the solid has a density of 2.4 g/ml.

Is that still the case at the very surface of the solid? Like, if I were to plot the pressure field, would there be an abrupt jump from right at the interface between both objects (since pressure depends on density)? Idk why but that seems wrong to me but I can't quite put my finger on why.

The other question is, as long as the density of the solid is higher than that of the fluid, the gradient of the pressure field should have a tendency to push the fluid away to minimize pressure up to uniformity. Said otherwise, if one quantizes space and looks at the average pressure on a cell, cells containing portions of the solid will have larger densities than the surrounding fluid, making the fluid want to move away to distribute the pressure across the simulation space.

But then that means that if the solid has a lower density than the fluid, the fluid will want to move into the space occupied by the solid, thus pressure differentials alone cannot explain why water doesn't move into the solid, what other forces play a role in keeping the water outside of the space occupied by the solid?

Comment: You will want to look up the Beavers-Joseph boundary condition :-)

Comment: For a fluid (which can be a gas or a liquid like water) in a solid container the surface of the container imposes two constraints. First, the normal component of fluid velocity at the solid surface vanishes, i.e., the solid boundary is impermeable (there are exceptions). Second, the solid surface imposes a constraint on the tangential fluid velocity at the boundary. The solid surface can be slippery or non-slippery, which depends on physical and chemical properties of the solid and the fluid. E.g., making the surface non-smooth will enforce zero tangential velocity of the fluid at the surface.

Comment: @MaximUmansk, could you expand your comment into an answer? I think that you're already addressing the question.